# Tabs with Fragment life cycle

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

in my app i have a Tabs with fragment classes. i trying to refresh listView in "fragment a" with the new data i insert.
In "fragment b" i have EditText and Button ,that inserting text to the database.
in "fragment a" i have the ListView with the dataBase rows. when "fragment a" is "OnCreateView" i just put the dataBase on a "ArrayList" and past it to my baseAdapter.
but "onCreateView" not refreshing my new data every time i get into the "fragment a" else i goes to "fragment c" and "onDestroy" call on "fragment a".
so my result it was to call :   "setUserVisibleHint" override method, and check if it is visible and refreshing the list.
but i dont think it is the good practice .

[image]

what should i do?

**Class a**

```
  public class ListFragment extends Fragment{

        basAdapterCustom adapter;
        ListView lv;
        ArrayList<Clock> list;
        private DbHandler hand;
        Context context;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
            context = getActivity();

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");

            hand = new DbHandler(context);
            list = new ArrayList<Clock>();

            lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listOfShifts);
            adapter = new basAdapterCustom(list, getActivity());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            refreshList();
            return v;
        }



        //like on "resume":
        @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            // Make sure that we are currently visible
            if (this.isVisible()) {
                refreshList();
                if (!isVisibleToUser) {
                    // TODO stop
                }
            }
        }



        private void refreshList() {

            list = hand.getByWorkName();
            adapter = new basAdapterCustom(list,getActivity());

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

**class b:**

```
public class ClockFragment extends Fragment{


    DbHandler hand;


    Context context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clock, container,false);

        context = getActivity();

        hand = new DbHandler(context);

        return v;
    }


    // ADD to .Db
    public void addToDb(View v){
        hand.add(new Clock(0, dateDay));    

    }


}
```

**class mainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, OnPageChangeListener{

    public static final String TAG = "myClock";

    String[] tabMenu = {"FRAG A","FRAG B","FRAG C"};

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "OnCreate = MainActivity (Pager");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager );
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (String tabsNames : tabMenu) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabsNames).setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }

    //  public void transDialog(){
    //      Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    //  }





    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }




    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {        
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);      
    }

}
```

**PagetAdapter.class**

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "myClock";


    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        Log.d(TAG, " CLASS : TabPagerAdapter");
        switch (index) {
        case 0:

            return new ListFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ClockFragment();
        case 2:
            return new SettingFragment();

        default:
            break;
        }       
        Log.d(TAG, " CLASS : TabPagerAdapter = "+index);
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Please help me i hope you are understand my problem...

Comment: post that class in which you have initialize tabs.

Comment: where you are calling addtodb method in class B?

Comment: It's the button . (on xml -android:onClick:"addToDb")

Answer (score 0):

You want to update listView in fragment A, after insert data in fragment b? Then  you have a few solutions to choose:
**1.** Implement communications between fragments via activity. Then B insert date, it send message to activity, that data need to be updated. Then fragment A started, it's ask activity to need update data. For details on implementing this communication check [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).
**2.** Use some bus library, [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for example. Then fragment B insert data, it post 'data changed' event to bus. Fragment A checks on start if this event occurs.
**3.** Use [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) which "monitor the source of their data and deliver new results when the content changes."